# Jquerytools "scrollable" scroll to first page

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am using the jquerytools scrollable library.
http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/plugins.html#navigator

Navigation works all fine. But I have a couple dozen pages. So **I want to tell the slider to scroll to the first/last page.**
How can I do it?

Thats what I use so far.

```
$( ".items" ).css('left',0);
```

It works, only that the navigator buttons don't recognize that i scrolled O.o
What to do?

Comment: use the methods in the API, bottom of docs page

Answer (score 1):

this worked:

```
$form.find(".scrollable").data("scrollable").begin(0); // scroll to beggining of slider
```