# jQueryTools Scrollable - Loops through twice then stops on first slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, scrollable, jquery-scrollable

I am trying to figure out a way to go through a set of slides a couple of times and then return and stop on the first slide.

Currently, I have:

```
$('#con_featured .scrollable').scrollable({
    circular: false
}).navigator({  
    activeClass: 'current',
    navi:'#con_featured .scrollable_nav ul'
}).autoscroll({
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 8000
});
```

I did find an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126826/jquerytools-scrollable-scroll-to-first-page) on how to scroll back to the beginning of the slider. And I've seen the event "onSeek" that occurs after each item has scrolled. Is there a way to use that (or another event listener) to find when the slides end?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine was able to fix the issue by utilizing the [Scrollable API](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html). Using the API he was able to get the index of the slider and after it plays through twice, it stops on the first slide.

```
var loopCounter = 0;
$('#con_featured .scrollable').scrollable({
    onSeek: function() {
        var api = $('#con_featured .scrollable').data("scrollable");

        if(api.getIndex() == 0) {
            loopCounter++;
            if(loopCounter >= 2) api.stop(); // loops twice then stops
        }
    },
    circular: true
}).navigator({  
    activeClass: 'current',
    navi:'#con_featured .scrollable_nav ul'
}).autoscroll({
    autoplay: true,
    interval: 8000
});
```